# How do I embed JSX in javascript and allow callback?

Tags: reactjs

Given

```
var data = {
      value: <input type="text" value="Reg" onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
    };

var RawDataTable = React.createClass({
  generateTable() {
      <td className="myColumnStyle">
        {data.value}
      </td>
  },

handleValueChange(e){
  console.log('mischief managed');
},
```

I get a runtime error

> bundle.js:51060Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'handleValueChange' of undefined

The issue is that the `value` does not recognize `onChange={this.handleValueChange}`

In other words this works:

```
  <td className="performColumnStyle">
    <input type="text" value="Reg" onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
  </td>
```

But what I want (and what errors out) is this:

```
  <td className="performColumnStyle">
    {data.value}
  </td>
```

I think the model is trying to convert the JSX in the model object itself as opposed to the React.createClass object.  How can I do this?

### Update

I envision react-bootstrap's [modal dialogue](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live).  In such a case I can do:

```
<Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
</Modal.Body>
```

Here we provide any content and it becomes a part of the modal.  I'd like to setup something similar for a column.

I can setup my code like this and it will work:

```
<MyTable.column>
  <input type="text" value="Reg" onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
<MyTable.column>
```

I am asking if it's possible in react to do this instead ?:

```
<MyTable.column>
  {data.value}//Maybe I have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to do this?
<MyTable.column>
```

Comment: Could you supply a bit more context?  Where is `data.value` being created / instantiated?  Is it being passed via props, or set in the `render()` function?

Comment: @MichaelParker - Updated question.  Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: where are you assigning that JSX to `value`? Looks like the context is different.

Comment: I take it `handleValueChanges` is also a method of the class `RawDataTable`?

Comment: Would you be able to answer why you need to declare a `data.value` variable that exists outside of your class declaration?  This might help me give you an answer that works for you.

Comment: I need to provide the ability to provide HTML as the value for a column in a table.  Imagine a grid with an editable field which is a textbox.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey are you binding `handleValueChanges`? Can you show the whole component please?

Comment: @Ursus - The whole component is much too complex. The noise would drown out the root of the question.  I'm not specifically calling bind anywhere.  It's defined exactly as shown in the question, as part of the React.createclass object

Comment: Mmm a component that is too complex doesn't smell good ;) Also `data` doesn't seem look like valid `json`. I don't think you can use JSX outside the scope of `React.createClass`.

Comment: If the idea is to allow users to explicitly define HTML to be rendered on your page, perhaps what you're looking for is the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute.  Your users could pass a valid HTML static markup string which can be rendered into some `<div>` with that attribute specified.  More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind the method to the class or component please sir if you dont you get undefined. see examples below

```js
class SearchBar extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {term: ''};
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({term: event.target.value });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //fetch weather data
    this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
    this.setState({term: ''});

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">
        <input
          placeholder="Get a five day forecast in you favrite cities"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
         />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class App extends component{

constructor(props){
super(props);
  //you have to bind the method
this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this)
}

render(){

  //call you method

}

}
```

Comment: The problem I'm dealing with is specifically with the separate data model (not a react component).  I'm not sure how to translate this answer to my issue with the data model.  Can you adjust this answer to fit the issue of passing in a data model (which is an JS object and not a react component)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `this` in `this.handleValueChange` is only the right `this` **INSIDE** `React.createClass({...`.

Data is initialised outside of this function, which means that the context is difference, so `this` is simply the global object, which does not have the `handleValueChange` method.

Can you initialise data in the render method of RawDataTable? Like so:

```
var RawDataTable = React.createClass({
  methods () {..}

  render () {
    data = { 
      value: <input type="text" value="Reg" onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
    };
    return ( <more JSX here />)
  }
}
```

If you do this, it should find the handleValueChange function fine.

EDIT: If you are passing down the data as a prop from a parent component, presumably there are certain bits of the data that you want to put into the JSX that you're creating. So let's say your data is an array of objects:

```
var RawDataTable = React.createClass({
  methods () {..}

  render () {
    const myJSXFromData = this.props.data.map((myObj) => {
      return <input type="text" value="{myObj.someProp}" onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
    })
    return (
      {myJSXFromData}
      <more JSX here />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Initializing data inside of React.createClass is not an option.  Because in production the value for `data` will be passed in as a property from the parent component.

Comment: In that case you should pass your data down in whatever form it comes in and map over it in the render function, like:
`const myJSX = data.map(x => <input ..... onChange={this.handleValueChange})`

Comment: Or you could also pass down the handleValueChange function from the same parent where you create the data object.

Comment: I need to do do this in the context of the React.createClass object.  Because besides the callback I also need to create variables to track the state of the input box.  If you can update the answer to show your mapping example that might solve it.  I feel like that's what I'm already doing because generateTable() is called as part of the render() function.  So I'd need to see a working example.

Comment: updated. It's not what you're already doing because crucially, you're trying to set `this.handleValueChange` from somewhere outside React.createClass. This approach avoids that

Comment: This solution would work, but it requires that I give up the ability for the user to pass me the html.  Maybe that's what I have to do.